# HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL - getting error with RequestDispatcher

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, http-status-code-405

I'm creating a login page and want to hide `.jsp` into URL bar, So i tried to use the following:

Here my `loginPage.jsp`:

```
<form class="m-t-md" action="loginAccount">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" password="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Login</button>
    <a href="forgot.html" class="display-block text-center m-t-md text-sm">Forgot Password?</a>
    <p class="text-center m-t-xs text-sm">Do not have an account?</p>
    <a href="signup" class="btn btn-default btn-block m-t-md">Create an account</a>
</form>
```

here is my `login` where i'm calling `loginPage.jsp` using `RequestDispatcher`:

```
public class login extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException{

        response.setContentType("text/html");


        RequestDispatcher RequetsDispatcherObj =request.getRequestDispatcher("./loginPage.jsp");
        RequetsDispatcherObj.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Which gives me this error:

***[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubwN8.png)***

I did used as well `doPost` instead `doGet` but still getting the same error.

***HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!!***

**EDITED**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false">

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.pages.index</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.pages.login</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>loginAccount</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.login.loginAccount</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>loginAccount</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/loginAccount</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: You implementation seemed to be correct, can you also post the contents of your web.xml file? I just want to see that loginAccount is mapped to your login servlet.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have 2 servlets here pertaining to login. One is `com.pages.login` and another `com.login.loginAccount`. However, your form submission will be passed on to your `com.login.loginAccount` (and not to your `com.pages.login` servlet). This is clearly indicated in the action attribute of your form:

```
<form class="m-t-md" action="loginAccount">
```

You posted code from your `com.pages.login` servlet. However, it is not the one handling the form submission. You can do one of the following:

Edit your servlet `com.login.loginAccount`. Make sure that `doGet`
   method is declare to handle the form submssion.

```
package com.login;

public class loginAccount extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException{
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Or you can update your form element, add method attribute and set it 
   to POST

```
<form class="m-t-md" action="loginAccount" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form says `action=loginAccount`, `/loginAccount` url is mapped to servlet name `loginAccount`. Servlet `loginAccount` points to class `com.login.loginAccount`. You may point the `/loginAccount` mapping to servlet with name `login`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/loginAccount</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

OR

Change your form action to `login`